# Apply range filter on a store ExtJS

Tags: filter, grid, extjs4.1, extjs5, extjs6

I have a requirement where I need to apply the already saved filters from response to the **ExtJS grid filters**.Everything is fine but when I get two filters on a single column say '**lt**' and '**gt**' for a **numeric filter** am unable to filter the data.

```
    var store=grid.getStore();
    store.filter({operator:'lt',value:500,property:'count'},
    {operator:'gt',value:100,property:'count'});//applying both less than 
    and greater than range filters
```

Here I am sending both the 'lt' and 'gt' filters.But only one of them is being sent as request to server.So the store is not getting filtered exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- By default, the filters in store's filter collection are grouped by "property". You can specify the "id" property to prevent this.
- You also missed to pass the parameter as array.

  ```
  store.filter([{
      id: 'count-lt',
      operator: 'lt',
      property: 'count',
      value: 500
  }, {
      id: 'count-gt',
      operator: 'gt',
      property: 'count',
      value: 100
  }]);
  ```